# Как спарсить данные с торговой площадки steam?

Tags: python, python-3.x, парсер, steam, crawling

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Откуда и как парсить эти данные? [Ссылка](https://steamcommunity.com/market/listings/730/Fracture%20Case)

Comment: Очень красивый график. Думаю, что если этот график строится в  реальном времени, то, скорее всего, данные к нему поступают через вебсокет, а всё рисование происходит на клиенте. Можно попробовать разобраться в коде страницы, и сэмулировать работу браузера.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Берём Вашу [страницу](https://steamcommunity.com/market/listings/730/Fracture%20Case). Делаем запрос с помощью браузера / curl / postman и получаем текст страницы. Далее, смотрим значения на графике, например, `28 августа` в `1 PM` было продано `1814` предметов по `$1.88`. Давайте в теле ответа найдём эти данные. Нажимаем `ctrl+F` и ищем подстроку: `var line1=` или же `1814`. Здесь будет лежать огромный массив, в котором и будет всё то, что Вам требуется.

Answer (score 2):

Кодовое дополнение [ответа hedgehogues](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1176583/201445):

```
import json
import re

import requests


rs = requests.get('https://steamcommunity.com/market/listings/730/Fracture Case')

m = re.search(r'var line1=(.+);', rs.text)
data_str = m.group(1)

data = json.loads(data_str)
print(data)
# [['Aug 07 2020 01: +0', 10.698, '57688'], ['Aug 08 2020 01: +0', 6.926, '48599'], ...
```